# Which formats is use to play video or audio in iOS library?

Tags: ios, audio, video, format, streaming

what kind of format is acceptable to play and streaming video and audio on iOS for developing application?

Comment: Read the "Multimedia Programming Guide" in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Apple’s iOS Technology Overview [page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007898-CH9-SW4) :

iOS supports many industry-standard video formats and compression standards, including the following:

- H.264 video, up to 1.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Low-Complexity version of the H.264 Baseline Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48 kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats
- H.264 video, up to 768 Kbps, 320 by 240 pixels, 30 frames per second, Baseline Profile up to Level 1.3 with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48 kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats
- MPEG-4 video, up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Simple Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48 kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats
- Numerous audio formats, including the ones listed in “Audio Technologies”

iOS supports many industry-standard and Apple-specific audio formats, including the following:

- AAC
- Apple Lossless (ALAC)
- A-law
- IMA/ADPCM (IMA4)
- Linear PCM
- µ-law
- DVI/Intel IMA ADPCM
- Microsoft GSM 6.10
- AES3-2003